# Switch between two widgets depending on a delay

Tags: flutter, timer, future

I have got a state variable `a`. I want to show widget `A` if variable `a` is `100.0`. If variable `a` is different, then I want to show widget `B`.

This is easy and looks like this:

```
      child: aOrB(a),  // somewhere in the top-level Scaffold

...

Widget aOrB(double a) {
  if (a == 100.0) {
    return A;
  } else {
    return B;
  }
}
```

But here is the catch: If variable `a` is changed to `100.0`, I want to show widget `B` first and after some delay switch to widget `A`.

And another catch: If user taps to widget `A`, I want to show widget `B` for some time and then after some delay show widget `A` again.

The conditions summed into a table:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      a == 100.0     |         A        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      a != 100.0     |         B        |
|---------------------|------------------|
| a == 100.0; t < 5 s |         B        |
|  A.onTap; t < 5 s   |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I've already experimented with Future.delayed, Timer and a Visibility widget, but not successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally the following worked for me. Future.delayed is nice, but it can not be cancelled, when the Future is called several times in a row. This way user can run multiple 5 s delayed Futures in few seconds (either by onTap, or by changing the value of `a`, or by running setState too often). This makes onTap completely unusable, because the running Futures beat onTaps and hide widget `B` regardless of the user actions. This makes the @Naveen Avidi's answer not quite useful in reality.

So you need a Timer in order to do that. And you need to run it async in background. I've found, that the only place, where one could run a timer in background, is before return in `build()` method. The code here is called every time app is redrawn, so you can check, if `a` really changed, if you really want to run a Timer, cancel the previous Timer and run a new one.

The easiest way to listen for setState changes in `a` is to duplicate `a`'s value and compare it every time the app is redrawn. Which is exactly the same place in code.

```
double previousA;
bool showB;
Timer bTimer;

...

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  if (previousA != a) {
    if (a == 100.0) {
      showB = true;
      bTimer?.cancel();
      bTimer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
        setState(() => showB = false);
      });
    } else {
      showB = true;
    }
    previousA = a;
  }
  return Scaffold(

...

        child: aOrB(showB),

...

aOrB(showB){
  if (showB == true) {

  } else {

  }
}
```

If you also want to set showB somewhere in your code no matter `a` hasn't changed, you can also duplicate showB and listen for its changes:

```
if (previousShowB != showB) {
  if (showB == true) {
    bTimer?.cancel();
    bTimer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      setState(() => showB = false);
    });
  }
}

...

setState(() => showB = true);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example for what I understood !
It works for a == 100, a != 00 and time delay on on tap.
Modify it as your requirement !

```
double a = 100;

  Widget focusedWidget;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    //if you want to predefine a initial widget call the initWidget method !
    //or call the changeWidget for instant output

    changeWidget(a);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Let\'s parse some JSON'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 10, 5, 10),
          child: focusedWidget,
        ));
  }

  void initWidget(flag) {
    if (flag == 100) {
      setState(() {
        focusedWidget = Card(
          color: Colors.green,
          child: ListTile(
              onTap: () {
                changeWidget(50);
                //or some value
              },
              title: Text('Widget A',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
        );
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        focusedWidget = Card(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: ListTile(
              onTap: () {
                changeWidget(100);
              },
              title: Text('Widget B',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
        );
      });
    }
  }

  void changeWidget(flag) {
    if (flag == 100) {
      setState(() {
        focusedWidget = Card(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: ListTile(
            onTap: () {
              changeWidget(100);
              //or some value
            },
            title: Text('Widget B',
                style:
                    TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center),
          ),
        );
      });
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
        setState(() {
          focusedWidget = Card(
            color: Colors.green,
            child: ListTile(
              onTap: () {
                changeWidget(50);
              },
              title: Text('Widget A',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center),
            ),
          );
        });
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        focusedWidget = Card(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: ListTile(
            onTap: () {
              changeWidget(100);
            },
            title: Text('Widget B',
                style:
                    TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center),
          ),
        );
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: This looks so easy, how could I be so dumb? :D

Comment: It does not do anything if variable `a` is changed

Comment: I don't know what's happening in your code ! Post your code then ask the questions

Comment: I change variable `a` in many places in my script using `setState`. The widget should react to these state changes and redraw itself according to a value of `a`

Comment: This is my app: https://pastebin.com/fnxgQHtJ. Variable `a` is variable `song`, `index` and `_rate` (all three of them). Widget `AorB` is widget `_album`, you can see the widgets A and B inside of it (Center and Image/Icon). The real code is much more complicated as you can see and it will be even much more complicated after I implement a solution to this issue

Comment: Basically I'm asking for a way to run `changeWidget` every time `a` changes somewhere in code. But this was already described in my original question

Comment: There is a lot of code man ! If u want to change widget if a is changed, then where you are allowing or changing a value call changeWidget !!!???

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Another thing is that when you call `changeWidget` several times in a row, it makes several calls of Future.delayed. But you only need the last call, the others cause issues with redraw.

Comment: Well ! At the beginning you just posted how to do a task ! And I just tried how to do !